# How to change fieldLabel style in extjs4

Tags: extjs4.1

I want to know is there any method to change the font color, font size and font family of  field label of entire panel or  entire project in extjs4.1.0.(for example i have some 10 js files with 10 form panels. I want to change fieldlabel style, without altering in each js. Is there any method to achieve this???)
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[fieldlabel's css class](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Labelable-cfg-labelCls) is 'x-form-item-label'.

You can create your own css style to this class, by for example, including the following in the `<head>` of your index.html:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .x-form-item-label
        color: red !important;
    }
</style>
```

Just make sure it comes after the inclusion of the ext css file.

Comment: And one more problem with grid data model in extjs4.1.0 The field names are appending with id. Do u know how to remove idProperty in data model. If u know pls let me knw:)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this, does the DOM element gets an id, or does the label itself gets an idea? Regardless, it would be appropriate to start a new question on this so others can help you and more can find it in the past. Just make sure to be clear on the problem.